# About convergence in norm of the Fourier Transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Duoandikoetxea's *Fourier Analysis*, on page 59 (Corollary 3.7) says that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\big\|S_{R}\,f - f\big\|_{p} = 0
\end{equation}

for $1<p<\infty$, where $S_{R}\,f \:$ is such that $\widehat{S_{R}\,f}\left(y\right)$ = $\chi_{(-R,R)}\left(y\right) \,\hat{f}(y)$. He also proves that there is a constant $C_{p}$ such that $||\,S_{R}\,f\,||_{p} \le C_{p}\|\,f\|_{p}$, and that this $C_{p}$ doesn't depend on $R$.

After that he says that this is not true when $p=1$, but he doesn't give a counterexample. What function would contradict this when $p=1$?

Another thing, he obtains the limit above as a consequence of $\|\,S_{R}\,f\,\|_{p} \leq C_{p}\,\|f\|_{p}$. I can prove the limit above for all $f \in L^{p}$ if I know that it is valid for a dense subset, let's say, $S(\mathbb{R})$ (Schwartz class) or $C^{\infty}_{c}$ by approximating $f$ using such functions. How do I prove the limit above for $f$ in any of these spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure about this result in particular, but a *lot* of results hold for just $1<p<\infty$. $L^1$ is special for several reasons, which boil down to the fact that it is not the dual of anything (the dual of $L^\infty$ is a superset of $L^1$). This means that for instance the closed unit ball in $L^1$ is not weak star compact, whereas the closed unit ball in $L^p$ is weak star compact for $1<p<\infty$. The standard example of this compactness failure is $f_n(x) = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have that $\|S_R f\|_{p}\le C_p\|f\|_{p}$ for some constant $C_p >0$, $p\in (0,\infty)$. Since Schwartz functions are dense in $L^p$, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $g\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $\|f-g\|_{p}<\varepsilon$.

\begin{align}
\|S_R f-f\|_{p} & \le\|S_R f-S_R g\|_{p}+\|S_R g-g\|_{p}+\|g-f\|_{p}\\
& \le (1+C_p)\|f-g\|_{p}+\|S_R g-g\|_{p}
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
g(x) & =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{|\xi|<R} \hat g(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}d\xi\\
& =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} S_R g
\end{align}

So for $\varepsilon >0$ as above, there exists a $\tilde R>0$ such that $|S_R g-g|<\varepsilon$ for all $R>\tilde R$. Thus, for all $R>\tilde R$, $\|S_R f-f\|_{p}<C\varepsilon$. But $\varepsilon$ is arbitary.

Comment: Why does the convergence holds for $g$ in the Schwartz class?

Comment: Are you referring to the $L^p$ convergence? Hmm never really think deep about it, but in my opinion it basically boils down to the fact that the Fourier transform is a homeomorphism from $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to itself, and since you're working with Schwartz function, you are allowed to change order of integration/differentiation. I'm going to refer you to this notes: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218b_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf look for Theorem 1.17, you could easily check that those condition holds so you have $L^p$ convergence.

Comment: Also, I'm implicitly assuming that you know the Fourier inversion formula holds for Schwartz functions.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, it follows from the fact that you have inversion formula if $f$ is in Schwartz, i.e. 
$$f(x)=\int\hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}d\xi$$

Comment: Yes, but the convergence here is in norm. I don't see how this solves... :(